# Persons vs. People

Tags: word-choice

I saw a sign in an elevator that stated the capacity as "15 persons". What is the rule for when to use "persons" vs. "people"?

Answer (score -1):

*People* is always plural, so you can only use it with 2 or more persons. It is often used to refer to persons as a group in general.

*Person(s)* can be singular or plural, so you can use it with 1 or more persons. It is more suitable for counting as in the case of the maximum *number of people* allowed in an elevator.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering duplicates.

Comment: '_People_ is always plural' is not  phrased well, as you can use 'a people' /  but also 'various peoples'.

Comment: Sorry, but the app doesn't seem to show duplicate questions like it does when I submit a question from a computer and web browser.